# How to clone a git repository namespace

Tags: git

I want create a name space and push to a bare repo, here is what I have done, Push works, clone, pull did not.

GIT_NAMESPACE=work

created an empty repo and added come commits

done git push to a bare repo; in bare repo I did see namespace/work

Now

If I clone it, name space did not come.

I have same environment variable set.

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to git namespaces and decided to try it out. The following script is the result. It involves three repositories. The `sample` repository pushes to the work namespace of `sample-remote` bare repository. And, I'm cloning the work namespace of `sample-remote` into `sample-clone` repository.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

cd ~/Code
git init sample
cd sample
touch file
git add file
git commit -m "First commit"
git remote add origin ~/Code/sample-remote.git
git init --bare ~/Code/sample-remote.git
GIT_NAMESPACE=work git push origin master
cd ..
git clone ext::'git --namespace=work %s ~/Code/sample-remote.git' \
    sample-clone -b master
cd sample-clone
touch file2
git add file2
git commit -m "Second commit"
git push
```

Without the `-b master` argument, I got the following error:

```
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
```

and the working directory was empty.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the way you want to access the repository.

See [gitnamespaces(7)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitnamespaces.html).

Example for file system access:

```
git clone ext::'git --namespace=foo %s /path/to/repo.git'
```